# Aggregation, Association, Composition between sub-classes of the same super-class

Tags: java, uml

Can there be an association/ aggregation/ composition relationship between 2 sub-classes of the same super-class?

Comment: How about this scenario?

Device = Superclass
Remote and Television  = Subclasses 

Would an Association relationship between Remote and Television be legal/ good practice. If not, how could this scenario be modelled alternatively?

Comment: Why would you doubt that?

Answer (score 1):

If it conceptually makes sense yes; in fact you can even do it on the same (super)class.

[image]

For example a `Person` has two parents and an unspecified amount of children.

Similarly a forest can be composed of parts - e.g. northern part of the forest, southern, etc. But if you burn down the "parent" forest, all parts of the forest will be burned down.